# Python MySQL query gives no results while using Python variables in query

Tags: python, mysql, sql

The following python MySQL query to retrieve the feed_id from the MySQL table feed_master.

```
cur.execute('SELECT feed_id FROM feed_master WHERE url_link = %s',(source,))
rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print "Feed id : " + str(row)
```

- Python version : 2.7.10
- MySQL version : 5.6.27-0ubuntu1

On executing the above Python code, I get no results. However if I substitute %s with the actual string, I get the result I am expecting. The source variable is also passed to the function, as I tested the "source" variable with a print statement. Why doesn't the above code return the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is malformed.  The `%s` needs single quotes around it.  So, this might do what you want:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT feed_id FROM feed_master WHERE url_link = '%s'""",(source,))
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. It seems that this format is not documented, I did quite a lot of searches before asking the question.

Comment: Now MySQL is throwing an exception saying _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'http://petroleum-economist.com/RSS.aspx?FeedID=2155''' at line 1")

Comment: I changed the code to the one below, and it works for me, though I really don't have a clue why it does! Hope this helps somebodycur.execute("""SELECT feed_id FROM feed_master WHERE url_link = '%s' """ %(source))

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the code in all possible ways and the following executes perfectly

```
cur.execute("""SELECT feed_id FROM feed_master WHERE url_link = '%s' """ %(source))
```

I have no idea why it works, but hope it helps somebody facing the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to run the query is your original

```
cur.execute('SELECT feed_id FROM feed_master WHERE url_link = %s',(source,))
```

It looks like you can then iterate through the cursor:

```
for feed_id in cur:
    print feed_id
```

This might wind up printing a tuple with a single element, but that's pretty easy to fix by changing `feed_id` to `feed_id,` I can't tell you why the fetchall method isn't working though.

The reason your change works is that you're using Python's (old) string formatting syntax to replace %s with whatever the value of source is rather than using the database client to replace the variable properly. It's incredibly insecure to use Python string replacement in a SQL statement where the value you're replacing %s with is a user input. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection